# MySQL data not available fast enough

Tags: php, ios, mysql, web-services

I'm building an iOS app that uses a web-service. This web-service is built in PHP.

Now I'm building a function to rate movies. The database has the following tables:

```
Movie
MovieID --- Title --- DateAdded
```

and

```
Watched
UserID --- MovieID --- Rating --- DateWatched
```

I don't have all the movies in the database, but I use an API for that.

The process of rating a movie consists of the following:

```
1. Is the movie available in the `Movie` table?
  NO: Get the movie from the API and put it in the `Movie` table.
  YES: Do nothing.

2. Is the movie available in the `Movie` table? (a second check)
  NO: Rating the movie failed. Send back an error.
  YES: Put the movie with rating in the `Watched` table.
```

Now is the problem that the first time a movie is rated, so when it's not in the `Movie` table, it gets inserted but that's NOT visible at the second check. So I'm guessing that the PHP is faster than the database.
To check this I put `sleep(4)` before the second check. When I do this, it works.

The checks look like this:

```
$stmt = $this -> db -> prepare
("
    SELECT MovieID
    FROM Movie
    WHERE MovieID = ?
");
$stmt -> bind_param("i", $movieID);
$stmt -> execute();

$stmt -> store_result();

$numberOfRowsMovies = $stmt -> num_rows;

$stmt -> close();

if ($numberOfRowsMovies == 0) // movie not in DB yet
{
    // insert movie into 'Movie' table
    // or send FAILED message back
}
```

So, at the second check, `$numberOfRowsMovies` is 0, while it should be 1.

EDIT// something to note: the database is empty. So it isn't too slow because of too much records.

Comment: Use [affected_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) to count the result of UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE statements, not `num_rows` which is for SELECT statements

Comment: If affected_rows gives back 1, does that guarantee that there is actually 1 row inserted? Or is it just according to the statement?

Comment: If you execute an INSERT query statement, then check affected_rows for that statement and it returns a 1, then that insert was successful

Comment: Hmm. As it turns out it is still not working. The two tables have a foreign key `MovieID`. Could is be that it can't be inserted in the `Watched` table because it isn't in the `Movie` table yet? The strange thing is, sometimes the movie gets rated succesfully, but 70% of the time you have to do it twice... `$this -> db -> autocommit(TRUE);` is at the beginning of the file, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Testing for an error after executing the insert statement should tell you if there's a constraint problem

Comment: Well, as it seems `$stmt -> execute();` is failing. After this, no echo is working. Even putting it in a try-catch doesn't do anything: all code after `$stmt -> execute();` doesn't get executed. Even `echo $stmt -> error;` not. Debugging without any error ...

Comment: Well, it was actually my problem. The INSERT query is dynamic, because there need to be inserted a different amount of genres everytime. There was a comma at the end of the query. But still ... why are there just no errors?